# How to test Razorpay Subscriptions in Test Mode?

Tags: razorpay

I am building a Razorpay Subscription Flow. But for that, I have to test the functionality for development purposes. It is not accepting the cards as given in the [Razorpay Test Cards](https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/test-card-upi-details/). It is showing the error `This card does not support recurring payments`.

[image]

In such a situation, how can I test this functionality?

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently I encountered the same alert while integrating razorpay subscription feature for one of my client and after spending a lot of time I came to know the problem is not at razorpay end, but RBI has given new mandate for domestic recurring payments.

Please look into this article from razorpay for details.

https://razorpay.com/docs/announcements/rbi-card-payments/subscriptions/

I have cross checked and verified with razorpay team too.

Also for now you can enable UPI payment for subscription feature from razorpay dashboard, as it works fine and card payment would be enabled once all banks will follow the new guidelines.

Hope it would be helpful for you.